# How to reference a DataRow explicitly in the code behind and show/hide based on another DataRow value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In a DetailsView I have set visible = false for a TemplateField with HeaderText of "No Treatment Reason:".
In the code behind how can I reference the DataRow explicitly and make it visible based on the value of the other TemplateField with the HeaderText of "Care Plan Intent:" ?

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvTest" FooterStyle-Width="100%" Font-Bold="false" BackColor="#A2C4EA" 
    FieldHeaderStyle-Width="35%" BorderWidth="1" CellSpacing="2" Font-Names="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" 
    Font-Size="12px" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" AllowPaging="False" style="width:98%"
    HeaderStyle-BackColor="White" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
<Fields>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Care Plan Intent:">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label skinid="tablabelblack" id="lblIntent" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CarePlanIntent") %>' />
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidCarePlanIntent" Value='<%# Eval("CarePlanIntent") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No Treatment Reason:" Visible="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label skinid="tablabelblack" id="lblNoTreatmentReason" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NoTreatmentReason") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: You cannot make a `DataRow` visible, so its not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter - server side, what code would show/hide the templatefield/row marked, rightly or wrongly, as visible=false. Can I refer to it by name rather than by rank or order?

Comment: What is the datasource of the `DetailsView`?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter There is a protected sub which simply calls a sql server stored procedure and passes in a single value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `DataBound` event and cast the `DataItem` to the correct type (f.e. `DataRowView`). You can use `FindControl` to get your controls and following LINQ query to get the correct column to make it (in)visible:

```
protected void dvTest_DataBound(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var noTreatCol = this.dvTest.Fields.Cast<DataControlField>()
        .First(field => field.HeaderText == "No Treatment Reason:");
    DataRow row = ((DataRowView) dvTest.DataItem).Row;
    Label tablabelblack = (Label)dvTest.FindControl("tablabelblack");
    HiddenField hidCarePlanIntent = (HiddenField)dvTest.FindControl("hidCarePlanIntent");
    string value = row.Field<string>("Value"); // just an example
    noTreatCol.Visible = value == "SomeValueThatMakesItVisible";
}
```

---

> Is it possible to do that in VB and without LINQ?

Of course:

```
Protected Sub dvTest_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim row As DataRow = DirectCast(dvTest.DataItem, DataRowView).Row
    Dim tablabelblack As Label = DirectCast(dvTest.FindControl("tablabelblack"), Label)
    Dim hidCarePlanIntent As HiddenField = DirectCast(dvTest.FindControl("hidCarePlanIntent"), HiddenField)

    Dim value As String = row.Field(Of String)("Value") ' just an example '
    Dim noTreatColIndex As Int32 = -1
    For i As Int32 = 0 To Me.dvTest.Fields.Count - 1
        Dim field = dvTest.Fields(i)
        If field.HeaderText = "No Treatment Reason:" Then
            noTreatColIndex = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If noTreatColIndex > -1 Then
        dvTest.Fields(noTreatColIndex).Visible = value = "SomeValueThatMakesItVisible"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: is it possible to do that in VB and without LINQ?

Comment: @PaulStevens: of course, edited my answer. Note that i've added the label and the hiddenfield only to show hwo you can get them. Currently the code only switches the visibility of the complete column.